# angular-cli, route.hash = true and ng build

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I use angular-cli and `router.forRoot({hash: true})`. When I run `ng build` it gives me a `<base href="/">` added to the generated `index.html` which screws up the loading of the app.

I want to use `route.hash = true` and not having to delete each time the tag `<base href="/">` from the generated `dist/index.html`.

How to avoid this?

Comment: Excuseme, English is not my first language. I wanted to say 'it gives me <base href="/"> added to the generated index.html', instead of 'it gives me a added to the generated index.html'. Hope to be clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

The `<base href="/">` is not dynamically added on build. At least not for beta 24 all the way to 1.0.0. It's static in `/src/index.html` just remove it from `/src/index.html` and it should not appear when you run `ng serve`

Comment: My version of angular-cli is 1.0.0-beta.22-1,I dont have <base href="/"> in my initial index.html and I have Router.forRoot({useHash: true}) in my app module, but running "ng build --prod" i get this <base href="/"> tag dynamically inserted. It is really annoying, but thanks anyway. I'll try to ask in the github repo.

Comment: youare using an old version, have considered updating?

Comment: Your probably are right. The problem is, I've spent a couple of days trying to update to the latest version (4) with no too much luck, but I gess it is question of time and patience :). Hope upgrading solves the problem. Thanks again.